# pyspark: what is the best way to select n distinct IDs from a dataset

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

There's a DataFrame in pyspark with data as below:

```
    id manager score
    A     x     3
    A     y     1
    B     a     2
    B     b     5
    C     f     2
    D     f     6
```

What I expect is exactly n IDs in the resulting dataset.

eg. If I say 3 IDs needed, then the resulting dataset would look like this:

```
id manager score
 A   x      3
 A   y      1
 B   a      2
 B   b      5
 C   f      2
```

So this dataset has 5 rows, but exactly 3 IDs as expected.
If I do a df.limit(3) it will be top 3 records only, since the IDs are repeating, I will get less than 3 IDs, i.e. only 2 in this case. How to proceed? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use spark sql queries to do this.

Just change the `limit` clause value in the subquery to choose number of distinct `id`.

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([("A", "x", "3"), ("A", "y", "1"), ("B", "a", "2"), ("B", "b", "5"), ("C", "v", "2"), ("D", "f", "6")], ["id", "manager", "score"])

+---+-------+-----+
| id|manager|score|
+---+-------+-----+
|  A|      x|    3|
|  A|      y|    1|
|  B|      a|    2|
|  B|      b|    5|
|  C|      v|    2|
|  D|      f|    6|
+---+-------+-----+

df.createOrReplaceTempView("employee")

sql("""select * from employee e1 
     inner join (  
        select distinct id as uni_id from employee order by uni_id limit 3) e2 
     on e1.id=e2.uni_id""").drop("uni_id").show() 

+---+-------+-----+
| id|manager|score|
+---+-------+-----+
|  A|      x|    3|
|  A|      y|    1|
|  B|      a|    2|
|  B|      b|    5|
|  C|      v|    2|
+---+-------+-----+
```

Comment: As for the resulting output, this answer is perfect, thanks! However, I would have to use the pyspark code. The logic helped me to code it in pyspark. Thank you.

Comment: @Daenerys, feel free to vote if this answer has helped you!.

Comment: @suresiva, you can avoid join by using `where id in (select distinct id ...limit 3)`. please check my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try `StringIndexer` which factorizes each string in `id` column and then `filter` according to the limit.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer

n = 3 #change as per limit
idx = StringIndexer(inputCol="id",outputCol="id_num")
idx.fit(df).transform(df).filter(F.col("id_num")<n).drop("id_num").show()
```

---

```
+---+-------+-----+
| id|manager|score|
+---+-------+-----+
|  A|      x|    3|
|  A|      y|    1|
|  B|      a|    2|
|  B|      b|    5|
|  C|      f|    2|
+---+-------+-----+
```

Comment: My n is 1000. I tried this, and finally when i check the result, as ```df.select("id").distinct().count()``` I should have got the result to be 1000, however got 54k. Not sure why the logic did not work for me. Also, I feel this is an expensive operation for this requirement.

Comment: Weird, did you save to a new df ? `df1 = idx.fit(df).transform(df).filter(F.col("id_num")<n).drop("id_num")` and then do `df1.select("id").distinct().count()` ? @Daenerys

Comment: yes you are absolutely right, it worked for me! earlier, I checked a cached result, so showed me a different count, my bad. thanks!! however, for now, I prefer to go with the inner join on the list of distinct ids. Thanks a lot, learned something new here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple approach using 'colllect_set' function and some pythonic operations:

```
idLimit=3 #define your limit

id_lst=(sourceDF  #collect a list of distinct ids
        .select(collect_set('id'))
        .collect()[0][0]
       )

id_lst.sort() #sort the ids alphabatically

id_lst_limited=id_lst[:idLimit] #limit the list as per your defined limit

targetDF=(sourceDF #filter the source df using your limited list
          .filter("id in ({0})".format(str(id_lst_limited)[1:-1]))
         )
```

Comment: Anytime mate! Please feel free to upvote my answer if it has helped you!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply avoid the **`join`** by **`where id in (select distinct id ...limit 3)`** as below-

```scala
 val df = Seq(("A", "x", "3"), ("A", "y", "1"), ("B", "a", "2"), ("B", "b", "5"), ("C", "v", "2"), ("D", "f", "6"))
    .toDF("id", "manager", "score")
    df.show(false)

    /**
      * +---+-------+-----+
      * |id |manager|score|
      * +---+-------+-----+
      * |A  |x      |3    |
      * |A  |y      |1    |
      * |B  |a      |2    |
      * |B  |b      |5    |
      * |C  |v      |2    |
      * |D  |f      |6    |
      * +---+-------+-----+
      */

    df.createOrReplaceTempView("employee")
    spark.sql("select * from employee where id in (select distinct id from employee order by id limit 3)")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---+-------+-----+
      * |id |manager|score|
      * +---+-------+-----+
      * |A  |x      |3    |
      * |A  |y      |1    |
      * |B  |a      |2    |
      * |B  |b      |5    |
      * |C  |v      |2    |
      * +---+-------+-----+
      */
```

Comment: @Daenerys have a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

I notice one of the answers above is based out of Spark SQL.

Here is another Spark SQL based approach, but with `WINDOW` clause -

```
sql("select id, manager, score from (select e1.id, e1.manager, e1.score, dense_rank() over (order by e1.id) as rrank from employee e1) where rrank <= 3").show()
```

Complete code -

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([("A", "x", "3"), ("A", "y", "1"), ("B", "a", "2"), ("B", "b", "5"), ("C", "v", "2"), ("D", "f", "6")], ["id", "manager", "score"])

+---+-------+-----+
| id|manager|score|
+---+-------+-----+
|  A|      x|    3|
|  A|      y|    1|
|  B|      a|    2|
|  B|      b|    5|
|  C|      v|    2|
|  D|      f|    6|
+---+-------+-----+

df.createOrReplaceTempView("employee")


sql("select id, manager, score from (select e1.id, e1.manager, e1.score, dense_rank() over (order by e1.id) as rrank from employee e1) where rrank <= 3").show()

+---+-------+-----+
| id|manager|score|
+---+-------+-----+
|  A|      x|    3|
|  A|      y|    1|
|  B|      a|    2|
|  B|      b|    5|
|  C|      v|    2|
+---+-------+-----+
```